UI Not Updating Correctly After Removing Items from State in React
I’m working on a React application where I have a component that displays a list of added equipment. I’m using context to manage the state of the added equipment. The issue I’m facing is that when I remove an item from the list, the UI doesn’t always update correctly.
Here’s a brief overview of the problem:

The Equipment List: Items can be added or removed. When an item is removed, it gets removed correctly from the state, as confirmed by the console logs.

State Management: I’m using context to manage the list of added equipment and its associated data.

Issue: After removing an item, the UI sometimes still shows old or incorrect data. Specifically, the equipment list sometimes displays items that should have been removed, or it displays outdated information.


Here are the relevant code snippets:
AddedEquipments.js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import { v4 } from "uuid";
import AddedEquipment from "./addedEquipment";
import data from "../../api/greelineProducts.json";
import { AddedEquipmentContext } from "../../context/addedEquipmentContext";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { ProductContext } from "./../../context/productContext";
import ProductModal from "./../modals/productModal";

function AddedEquipments(props) {
  const {
    addedEquipment,
    addEquipment,
    resetEquipments,
    setTotalConsumption,
    removeEquipment,
  } = useContext(AddedEquipmentContext);
  const { product } = useContext(ProductContext);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [consumption, setConsumption] = useState(0);
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState(data ? data[0] : {});

  useEffect(() => {
    setProductData(data[product]);
  }, [product]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log('AddedEqpt->'+JSON.stringify(addedEquipment))
    let aeCount = 0;
    addedEquipment.map((aE) => {
      aeCount += parseFloat(aE.usage);
    });
    setConsumption(aeCount);
    setTotalConsumption(aeCount);
  }, [addedEquipment, product]);



  const reset = () => {
    resetEquipments();
  };


  return (
    <div className="addedEquipments">
      {addedEquipment?.length > 0 && (
        <div className="paddedRow">
          <Row className="mainRow">
            {addedEquipment?.map((equipment, index) => (
              <Row key={equipment.id}>
                {/* Selected Equipment Component */}
                <div className="rowInline">
                  <div className="leftt">
                    {/* {console.log("Added Index: "+ index)} */}
                    {/* {console.log("Equipment: "+ JSON.stringify(equipment))} */}
                    <AddedEquipment equipment={equipment} index={index} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Row>
            ))}
          </Row>
          
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="blueBG">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <p className="consumptionHeading">
              {`Votre consommation électrique ${consumption} (en Wh/j)`}
            </p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          {addedEquipment?.length > 0 && (
            <Col xs={12}>
              <Button
                style={{ margin: "auto", bottom: 0 }}
                size="sm"
                variant="warning"
                onClick={() => {
                  reset();
                }}
              >
                Réinitialiser
              </Button>

              <Button
                disabled={consumption > productData?.puissance}
                style={{ margin: "auto", bottom: 0, marginLeft: 5 }}
                size="sm"
                variant="primary"
                onClick={() => {
                  consumption <= productData?.puissance && setShowModal(true);
                }}
              >
                Obtenir un devis
              </Button>
            </Col>
          )}
        </Row>
        <Row>
          {addedEquipment?.length == 0 && (
            <Col xs={12} style={{ color: "white" }}>
              0 équipements sélectionnés
            </Col>
          )}
        </Row>
      </div>
      <ProductModal
        isOpen={showModal}
        handleClose={() => setShowModal(false)}
        product={productData}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddedEquipments;

AddedEquipment.js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import { Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { FaTimesCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
import Badge from "react-bootstrap/Badge";
// import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Badge';
import { AddedEquipmentContext } from "../../context/addedEquipmentContext";
import ProgressBar from "react-bootstrap/ProgressBar";
import { findIndex } from "lodash";

function AddedEquipment(props) {
  const { addedEquipment, removeEquipment, updateUsage, updateSelectedOption } =
    useContext(AddedEquipmentContext);
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const [option, setOption] = useState(null);
  const [optionId, setOptionId] = useState(0);
  const [optionName, setOptionName] = useState("");
  const [usage, setUsage] = useState(1);
  const [totalWatt, setTotalWatt] = useState(0);
  const [customProduct, setCustomProduct] = useState("");
  const [optionDetail, setOptionDetail] = useState({});
  const [bar, setBar] = useState(0);
  const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);
  const [useEqt, setUseEqt] = useState(0);

  const equipmentAdded = props.equipment;
  const equipment = props.equipment;
  const index = props.index;
  //Remove Selected Equipment
  // const removeItemToArray = (obj) => {
  //   removeEquipment(obj);
  // };

  const removeaddedEquipment = (obj,index) => {
    removeEquipment(obj,index);
  };

  //Update Quantity
  const handleQuantity = (value) => {
    setQuantity(value);
    let val = Math.round(value * usage * option);
    updateSelectedOption(
      equipmentAdded?.id,
      value,
      usage,
      optionName,
      val,
      optionId
    );
    setTotalWatt(val);
    updateUsage(equipmentAdded.id, val);
  };

  //Update Equipment Option
  const handleOption = (id) => {
    let option = equipmentAdded?.options.find((i) => i.id == id);
    setOptionDetail(option);
    setOption(parseInt(option?.watt));
    setOptionName(option?.name);
    let val = Math.round(quantity * usage * parseInt(option?.watt));
    setOptionId(option?.id);
    if (option?.utilization) {
      updateSelectedOption(
        equipmentAdded?.id,
        quantity,
        option?.utilization,
        option?.name,
        val,
        option?.id
      );
    } else {
      updateSelectedOption(
        equipmentAdded?.id,
        quantity,
        usage,
        option?.name,
        val,
        option?.id
      );
    }
    setTotalWatt(val);
    updateUsage(equipmentAdded.id, val);
  };

  //Update Usage
  const handleUsage = (value) => {
    setUsage(value);
    let val = Math.round(quantity * value * option);
    setTotalWatt(val);
    updateSelectedOption(
      equipmentAdded?.id,
      quantity,
      value,
      optionName,
      val,
      optionId
    );
    updateUsage(equipmentAdded.id, val);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    //Count the sum of Consumption
    let aeCount = 0;
    console.log(addedEquipment)
    addedEquipment.map((aE) => {
      aeCount += parseFloat(aE.usage);
    });
    setBar(aeCount);

  }, [useEqt, bar, addedEquipment]);

  return (
    <Card className="addedEquipment">
      {/* <div className="removeIcon"><a href="#" className="removeIconLink" onClick={() => removeItemToArray(equipmentAdded)}><FaTimesCircle /></a></div> */}

      <Container className="addedEquipmentContainer">
        <Row className="rowWidth">
          
          {/* Options of the Equipment */}

          <div className="equipmentImgContainer">
            <div className="flexLeft ">
              <Image
                src={`${optionDetail?.image || equipmentAdded?.image}`}
                className="equipmentImage"
              />

              {/* <Card.Img variant="top" src={`${optionDetail?.image || equipmentAdded?.image}`} className="equipmentImage" /> */}
              <div className="rowFormat">
                <Form.Select
                  size="sm"
                  className="addedEquipmentForm"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    handleOption(e.currentTarget.value);
                  }}
                >
                  <option value={null}>Sélectionner</option>
                  {equipmentAdded.options?.map((o, i) => (
                    <option
                      value={o.id}
                      // value={parseInt(o.watt)}
                      name={o.name}
                    >
                      {o.name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </Form.Select>
              </div>
              

              {equipmentAdded?.id <= 2 && (
                <div className="rowFormat2">
                  {equipmentAdded.multipleQuantity && (
                    <div>
                      {/* <div className="addedLabel">Quantité</div> */}
                      <Form.Select
                        size="sm"
                        className="addedEquipmentForm"
                        onChange={(e) => handleQuantity(e.currentTarget.value)}
                      >
                        <option value={null}>Quantité</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                      </Form.Select>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              )}

              {equipmentAdded?.id !== 3 && (
                <div className="rowFormat3">
                  {/* {equipmentAdded?.id !== 3 && (
                <div className="addedLabel">Utilisation</div>
              )} */}

                  <div>
                    <Form.Select
                      size="sm"
                      className="addedEquipmentForm"
                      onChange={(e) => handleUsage(e.currentTarget.value)}
                    >
                      <option value={null}>Utilisation</option>
                      <option value="0.08">5 minute</option>
                      <option value="0.16">10 minutes</option>
                      <option value="0.25">15 minutes</option>
                      <option value="0.5">30 minutes</option>
                      <option value="0.75">45 minutes</option>
                      <option value="1">1 heure</option>
                      <option value="2">2 heures</option>
                      <option value="3">3 heures</option>
                      <option value="4">4 heures</option>
                      <option value="5">5 heures</option>
                      <option value="6">6 heures</option>
                      <option value="7">7 heures</option>
                      <option value="8">8 heures</option>
                      <option value="9">9 heures</option>
                      <option value="10">10 heures</option>
                      <option value="11">11 heures</option>
                      <option value="12">12 heures</option>
                      <option value="13">13 heures</option>
                      <option value="14">14 heures</option>
                      <option value="15">15 heures</option>
                      <option value="16">16 heures</option>
                      <option value="17">17 heures</option>
                      <option value="18">18 heures</option>
                      <option value="19">19 heures</option>
                      <option value="20">20 heures</option>
                      <option value="21">21 heures</option>
                      <option value="22">22 heures</option>
                      <option value="23">23 heures</option>
                      <option value="24">24 heures</option>
                    </Form.Select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}

              {equipmentAdded?.showWarning && (
                <Row className="warningRow">
                  <Col className="warning nopadding">
                    <img
                      alt={equipmentAdded.name}
                      variant="top"
                      className="warningImage"
                      src="warning.png"
                    />
                    <span className="warningText">
                      <b>Appareils à résistance</b>
                      <br />
                      Batterie au Lithium nécessaire
                    </span>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              )}
            </div>

            <div className="flexRight">
              <Badge bg="success" className="addedEquipmentBadge">
                {totalWatt} Wh/j
              </Badge>

              <div className="progressBarDiv">
                <div className="barText">
                  {parseInt((totalWatt / bar) * 100)}% de votre conso.
                </div>
                <ProgressBar
                  className="progress-custom"
                  variant="danger"
                  now={parseInt((totalWatt / bar) * 100)}
                  min={0}
                  max={100}
                  style={{ background: "gainsboro" }}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="delImageDiv">
                <img
                  className="delImage"
                  onClick={() => removeaddedEquipment(equipmentAdded,index)}
                  src={require("./delete-button.png")}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default AddedEquipment;

AddedEquipmentContext.js
import { add } from "lodash";
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const AddedEquipmentContext = createContext();

//This Context will store the selected Equipments
function AddedEquipmentContextProvider(props){
    const [addedEquipment, setAddedEquipment] = useState([]);
    const [totalConsumption, setConsumption] = useState(0);

    
    //Add Equipment to State
    function addEquipment(obj){
        setAddedEquipment(addedEquipment=>[...addedEquipment, obj])
        // console.log('Array->' + JSON.stringify(addedEquipment))
    }
    //Remove Equipment to State
    function removeEquipment(obj,index){
        setAddedEquipment(addedEquipment=>addedEquipment.filter((item, i) => i!==index))
       
        
    }

    //Reset
    function resetEquipments(){
        // console.log('newItems', newItems)
        setAddedEquipment([]);
    }

    //Update Puissance/Usage of the Object in State
    function updateUsage(id, val){
        let arrayCopy = [...addedEquipment];
        let selectedArray = arrayCopy.filter((item) => item.id === id);
        if(selectedArray.length>0){
            let selected=selectedArray[0];
            selected.usage=val;
            setAddedEquipment(arrayCopy);
        }
    }

    function setTotalConsumption(value)
    {
        setConsumption(value)
    }

    function updateSelectedOption(id, quantity, usage, option, total, optionId) {
        const selectedOption = { quantity, usage, option, total, optionId}
        
        let arrayCopy = [...addedEquipment];
        let selectedArray = arrayCopy.filter((item) => item.id === id);
        if(selectedArray.length>0){
            let selected=selectedArray[0];
            selected.selectedOption=selectedOption;
            setAddedEquipment(arrayCopy);
        }
    }

    const value = {addedEquipment, totalConsumption, addEquipment, removeEquipment, updateUsage, updateSelectedOption, resetEquipments, setTotalConsumption}
    
    return (
        <AddedEquipmentContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </AddedEquipmentContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default AddedEquipmentContextProvider;

Expected Behavior:

The power calculation of the remaining rows should remain correct after a deletion.

The image of the remaining rows should not change unexpectedly after a deletion.


Actual Behavior:

The power calculation of the row below the deleted one becomes incorrect.

The image in the row below the deleted one changes unexpectedly.



Usually when a problem occurs after an item is removed from a list it has something to do with the key property. I see you are doing quite a good job with the key: <Row key={equipment.id}>. But this line is suspicious: {equipmentAdded?.id <= 2 && ( - it suggest the identificators are consequent integer numbers. Are you sure they are all unique? Do you ever change the id after the object is created? I don't see anthing like that in the snippets you provided, but perhaps you removed some parts before posting the question to make it more concise...

The effect in AddedEquipments.js is also suspecious... Why consumption and totalConsumption are set to the same value?
